# Setting debug logs for community page

Tags: debugging

`document.cookie = "debug_logs=debug_logs;domain=.force.com"`;

I have used this code to set up debug log for my community page but it is not working.This was working when I logged in as a public site user. Please guide me how to set debug log for my community page. Thanks in advance

Comment: [Set up debug log](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_add_users_debug_log.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check your Domain name, the command you mentioned is for `.force.com` domain. Please use the appropriate command as below. You can find more details in this [link](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_debugging_guest_user.htm).

If you use a .force.com domain, use this command.

```
document.cookie="debug_logs=debug_logs;domain=.force.com";
```

If you use a custom domain (for example, yourCustomDomain.com), use this command.

```
document.cookie="debug_logs=debug_logs;domain=yourCustomDomain.com";
```

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issues as below. I can get debug logs to work for a test force.com site but not for a community. The Community URL uses force.com also. Should the document.cookie="debug_logs=debug_logs;domain=.force.com"; command not work for the community also?  Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue without any luck. It works on site but not community. I'm debugging the community guest user and inserted the cookie, but no log.